# Слово "по-ихнему" и подобные в словарях

Tags: лексика

В справочнике по пунктуации (в перечне вводных слов) видела наречие *по-ихнему* с пометой просторечное.  Насколько это правильно - включать подобные слова в справочник? Так и до матерных слов дойти можно. Они тоже бывают на вводные похожи.

Answer (score 3):

Просторечия относятся к экспрессивно-стилистической лексике, а всловари и справочники не включается лексика, характеризующаяся с точки зрения социально-диалектного состава(диалектизмы, профессионализмы, жаргонизмы, сленг). Так что всё верно.Просторечия используются в худ. литературе, например, для создания образа. Они должны быть в справочниках.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это связано с тем, что нет единой литературной нормы для всех стилей речи. Есть лексика, нормативна для разговорного стиля, книжного и нейтрального, художественного и т. д. Просторечные же слова фиксируются с тем чтобы определить, для какого стиля они подходят (например, для разговорного, который может быть использован в качестве приема и в художественных текстах). Просторечная лексика не являются аморальной, табуированной лексикой (в отличие от мата или вульгаризмов). И, судя по всему, имеет право на существование, несмотря на некоторую нежелательность этого явления. Также наверняка проще по возможности включать слова ограниченного предназначения в один справочник с пометой, чем создавать еще один.